# R cut zero-length interval

Tags: r

I have a column that has numeric values in the 1--7 range. I would like to use the `cut` function to split these values into the following intervals:
1 -> 1, 1.001-1.999 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2.001-2.999 -> 4, etc. I used the following line:

```
df$CAPECStmp = cut(df$AvgCAPEComputerScience,
               breaks=c(1,1.001,2,2.001,3,3.001,4,4.001,5,5.001), 
               labels=FALSE,
               include.lowest = TRUE)
```

However, 2.00 is mapped to 2, and not to 3 as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is working as designed; if you look at the documentation on `cut`, it will include the highest value in the group. If you don't want that behavior, you can set `right` to `FALSE`. This will include the lowest value.

```
df$CAPECStmp = cut(df$AvgCAPEComputerScience,
                   breaks=c(1,1.001,2,2.001,3,3.001,4,4.001,5,5.001), 
                   labels=FALSE,
                   include.lowest = TRUE, 
                   right = FALSE)
```